# Visitor Visa for 2 Years

Tags: visas, uk, tourist-visas

I visited to Uk in april 2016 and now i need 2 year visit visa, so please suggest me what kind of reason i need to mentioned in my application to get 2 year visa.

Kind Regards
ZM

Comment: Voting as unclear? You want a visa and you ask as the reason to give in the application? Just put down the reason why you want the visa. Never lie or make things up in visa applications!

Comment: Do you hope to stay in the UK for two years? If so, then you should not apply for a visitor visa, because they only allow stays of up to six months.

Answer (score 4):

First you need to decide exactly why you want the visa, and what you intend to do in the UK during the next two years.

Examine the different types of visa starting e.g. at [Visas and Immigration](https://www.gov.uk/browse/visas-immigration).

If what you want to do in the UK, the amount of time you want to spend there, your nationality etc. matches one of the visa or permit types, go ahead and apply for it.

If not, it means what you want to do is not permitted by UK law. Do not attempt to get a visa that does not match your actual intentions. Doing so puts you at all sorts of risk. Just browse some of the questions and answers here to see people trying to sort out the consequences of incorrect answers on visa forms.

A visitor visa may be appropriate if you intend several short visits to the UK over the next two years, while living somewhere else. If you intend to spend the next two years mainly in the UK, you would not be a visitor, and would only be able to do it by qualifying for a different visa type. As pointed out in a comment by Gayot Fow, they will not give a two year visitor visa until the person has a great performance history with 6 month visas.

Comment: +1, it's fine to add that they will not give a two year visa until the person has a great performance history with 6 month visas.

Comment: @GayotFow Is it safe to say that a single visit in April 2016 does not constitute "a great performance history"?

Answer (score 1):

There is no answer that will guarantee you a 2 year visit visa. You need to provide a genuine reason for requesting a visa, and then follow that with a reason why you want it for 2 years.

If you are suspected of violating your visa terms (for any reason) your visa will be cancelled, you will be detained and subject to deportation. If it was determined that you violated your visa terms in your previous visit - you may also be denied a visa, or denied entry.

If you provide false documents, you may be subject to further legal troubles. In most countries providing false documents is tantamount to fraud and you may be subject to arrest, fines, jail time, etc.

The bottom line is - do not attempt to lie, defraud or cheat your way into a visa. It will end badly.